# What is the proper name of a "doughnut sector" or "curved trapezoid"?

Tags: geometry, terminology

What is the name of this shape?

[image: Curved Trapezoid]

It is basically a sector with a doughnut hole cut out of it. Just wondering if it has a proper name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a sector of an [annulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_%28mathematics%29).  I would refer to it as an "annular sector".

Comment: [d3-shape](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape) document also mentions `annular sector`